# Spring mvc layout without tiles

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In Spring Mvc, beside using tiles, is there any way to decide the jsp layout. I mean think of a design with side menu panel and if I want to apeear each jsp for a relavent side menu, how can I do that without using tiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitemesh is another framework for jsp page layout: http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home

Answer (score 1):

You could crate sepatare jsp for each part of your page layout: header, footer, menu, etc.
And use:

```
<%@ include file="yourPageSection.jsp"%>
```

to include common parts in your pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the html or jsp design using the below.....

```
It works same as the master page of asp.Net......
<%@ include file="page.jsp"%>

<%@ include file="page.html"%>
```